characteristic functions of multivariate normal distribution
The characteristic function $ f(\mathbf{t}) $ of the random vector $\xi = (\xi_1, \cdots, \xi_n)'$ ,where $\xi_1, \cdots, \xi_n$ are mutually independent and the expectation vector of $\xi$ is $\mathbf{0}$ and the covariance matrix is $I$, satisfies $ f(\mathbf{t}) = f(U\mathbf{t}) $ for any orthogonal matrix $ U $. Prove that $\xi$ follows a multivariate normal distribution.
I can show that the characteristic function of the multivariate standard normal distribution satisfies the given condition. However, I have no idea how to show that this is the unique solution.
